# Do these limits exist? How do I calculate them?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} {\sin(x)\sin^3(x)\over\ 1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}$$
For the limit above, I assigned 0 to "x": $$\lim_{y\to 0} {0\over 1-\cos(y^2)} = 0$$
And assigning 0 to "y" gives me:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} {\sin(x).\sin^3(x)\over 1-\cos(x^2)}$$
Which is equal to $0\over 0$.

Is this enough to declare that the limit does not exist?

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} {xy+1\over x^2 + y^2}$$
And for this one above, assigning 0 to "x" and then "y" gives me: $$\lim_{y\to 0} {1\over y^2} = \infty$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0} {1\over x^2} = \infty$$
Should I prove the statement above with epsilon-delta definition of limits or this is enough and I can say the limit above is equal to $\infty$?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Have you tried *anything*?

Comment: You should try "simple" paths first, such as (but not limited to) fixing one coordinate equal to $0$ and making the other one tend to $0$, making both coordinates converge at equal speeds, making one coordinate converge faster than the other, etc..., and if you find two different limits then you know the overall limit does not exist. Finding the same limit along these different paths does not constitute a proof but you can then start getting your hands dirty trying to find such a proof knowing that *most likely* the claim is true, plus it gives you an idea of what the limit would be.

Comment: As for writing a question on this site, you need to show what you've attempted, where you think you're stuck, and provide context if needed. It's both a way to let the community help you in a way that is suited to your situation, and a way for you to see in more detail what you don't understand or don't see how to do, and doing that can sometimes let you find the answer by yourselves. It's also a matter of "putting as much time in your question as you would like someone to put in their answer" kind of deal.

Comment: $0/0$ is an indeterminate form, in the sense that it could be virtually anything, so you'd need to study it more in detail quantitatively. As for the second limit, finding the same limit on two paths is not enough. Hint: try going along $x = y$. And welcome to MSE! Hopefully my tendency to write blocks of text didn't scare you...

Comment: @BrunoB Your comments were really helpful Bruno and I appreciate it. Doesn't the third path which is x = y also give us infinity? Does this mean the function is limitless?

Comment: $x = y$ won't work for the second limit whoops, I need to remind myself that looking at the higher order monomials is for limits when $x$ goes to infinity, not towards $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first limit: the limit won't exist.
The path $(x,y) = (0,y)$ does yield $0$, but then for $(x,y) = (x, 0)$ you need to examine ths situation in more detail.
We have:
$$\frac{\sin(x)\sin^3(x)}{1 - \cos(x^2)} \underset{x \to 0}{\sim} \frac{x \cdot x^3}{\frac{(x^2)^2}{2}} \underset{x \to 0}{\sim} \frac{x^4}{\frac{1}{2}x^4} = 2 \neq 0$$
And as such we can conclude that the overall limit does not exist.

As for the second: the limit will actually be $+\infty$.
To prove it, I'll use the $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm here (in infinite-dimensional spaces, limits depend on the norm you choose, but in $\mathbb{R}^d$ all norms are equivalent so you can choose whichever one you think suits the proof best):
For $\|(x,y)\|_\infty \leq \frac{1}{2}$, we have:
$xy \geq - \frac{1}{4}$, thus:
$$\frac{xy + 1}{x^2 + y^2} \geq \frac{3}{4(x^2+y^2)} \geq \frac{3}{8 \|(x,y)\|_\infty^2} \quad\xrightarrow[\|(x,y)\|_\infty \to\ 0]{}\quad + \infty$$
Thus the overall limit is indeed $+\infty$.

This type of questions *does* depend on a fair share of trial and error but learning to check these kinds of path (and some other ones like $(x,y) = (x, x^2)$, etc...) is just like learning to check $0$, $\pm 1$ $\pm 2$, $\pm 3$ when checking roots of polynomials to hopefully have some quick factoring happen, or learning to add $0$ or multiply by $1$ cleverly, they're tricks you learn as you progress.

Answer (score 2):

For the first one the additional information already provided are very fine to conclude according to your idea.

For the second one, as an alternative to the fine way already given, we can also proceed by polar coordinates as follows

$${xy+1\over x^2 + y^2}=\frac{\rho^2\cos\theta\sin\theta+1}{\rho^2}=\cos\theta\sin\theta+\frac1{\rho^2}\to \infty$$

since $\cos\theta\sin\theta$ is bounded.